# Fill Textfield Based on Select Option

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm trying to get "hargaJual" value when I select some option. But when I insert a new row in the table and select a new option, it will change only the first row of "Harga" and leave the second-row blank.

Here's the result :

[image]

```
<td>
<select class="custom-select" id="kodeSparepart" name="kodeSparepart[]">
    <option value=""> --Pilih Sparepart-- </option>";
    @foreach($sparepart as $s) {
            <option value="{{ $s['kodeSparepart'] }}" data-price="{{ $s->hargaJual }}"> {{ $s['namaSparepart'] }} </option>";
     }
    @endforeach
 </select>
 </td> 
 <td> 
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="hargaJualTransaksi" name="hargaJualTransaksi[]" autocomplete="off" readonly> 
 </td>
```

And here is my javascript

```
    //for insert new row in table
 $(function(){
    $('#addMore').on('click', function() {
            var data = $("#tb tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#tb");
            data.find("input").val('');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#remove', function() {
        var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
            if(trIndex>=1) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        } else {
            alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");
        }
    });
});    
//fill hargaJualTransaksi field
$(function() {
    $('#kodeSparepart').on('change', function(){
        var price = $(this).children('option:selected').data('price');
        $('#hargaJualTransaksi').val(price);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event delegation on since the rows are dynamically rendered to the DOM :

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('change', '.kodeSparepart', function(){
        var price = $(this).children('option:selected').data('price');
        $('.hargaJualTransaksi').val(price);
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** The id attribute must be unique so you needs to change every `kodeSparepart` and `hargaJualTransaksi` to classes instead of id's, it will be something like :

```
<input class="form-control hargaJualTransaksi" type="text" name="hargaJualTransaksi[]" autocomplete="off" readonly>
```

Comment: thanks, now it can fill the others row of Harga, but both of the row get the last value of hargaJual from selected option.

Comment: You're welcome, You must change it too like : `<select class="custom-select kodeSparepart" name="kodeSparepart[]">`

Comment: Works now or not yet ?

Comment: Still have the same issue, I think its because it insert the hargaJual value into class .hargaJualTransaksi, and because of that, all of the field show the same hargaJual. But your answer basically answer my main question, so thanks for it :).

Comment: You're welcome, try `$(this).closest('tr').find('.hargaJualTransaksi').val(price);`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$("body").on('click', '#kodeSparepart', function (event) {
  var price = $(this).children('option:selected').data('price');
        $('#hargaJualTransaksi').val(price);
}
```